# Can I use setWorkerCacheMb in Apache Beam 2.0+?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Dataflow job (using Java SDK 2.1.0) is quite slow and it is going to take more than a day to process just 50GB. I just pull a whole table from BigQuery (50GB), join with one csv file from GCS (100+MB).

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key
I use sideInputs to perform join (the latter way in the documentation above)  while I think using CoGroupByKey is more efficient, however I'm not sure that is the only reason my job is super slow.

I googled and it looks by default, a cache of sideinputs set as 100MB and I assume my one is slightly over that limit then each worker continuously re-reads sideinputs. To improve it, I thought I can use `setWorkerCacheMb` method to increase the cache size.

However it looks `DataflowPipelineOptions` does not have this method and `DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions` is hidden. Just passing `--workerCacheMb=200` in `-Dexec.args` results in

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class.
null: InvocationTargetException:
Class interface com.xxx.yyy.zzz$MyOptions missing a property
named 'workerCacheMb'. -> [Help 1]
```

How can I use this option? Thanks.

My pipeline:

```
MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<TableRow> rows = p.apply("Read from BigQuery",
        BigQueryIO.read().from("project:MYDATA.events"));

// Read account file
PCollection<String> accounts = p.apply("Read from account file",
        TextIO.read().from("gs://my-bucket/accounts.csv")
                .withCompressionType(CompressionType.GZIP));
PCollection<TableRow> accountRows = accounts.apply("Convert to TableRow",
        ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, TableRow>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                String line = c.element();
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser();
                String[] fields = csvParser.parseLine(line);

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                row = row.set("account_id", fields[0]).set("account_uid", fields[1]);
                c.output(row);
            }
        }));
PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> kvAccounts = accountRows.apply("Populate account_uid:accounts KV",
        ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, KV<String, TableRow>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                TableRow row = c.element();
                String uid = (String) row.get("account_uid");
                c.output(KV.of(uid, row));
            }
        }));
final PCollectionView<Map<String, TableRow>> uidAccountView = kvAccounts.apply(View.<String, TableRow>asMap());

// Add account_id from account_uid to event data
PCollection<TableRow> rowsWithAccountID = rows.apply("Join account_id",
        ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                TableRow row = c.element();

                if (row.containsKey("account_uid") && row.get("account_uid") != null) {
                    String uid = (String) row.get("account_uid");
                    TableRow accRow = (TableRow) c.sideInput(uidAccountView).get(uid);
                    if (accRow == null) {
                        LOG.warn("accRow null, {}", row.toPrettyString());
                    } else {
                        row = row.set("account_id", accRow.get("account_id"));
                    }
                }
                c.output(row);
            }
        }).withSideInputs(uidAccountView));

// Insert into BigQuery
WriteResult result = rowsWithAccountID.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
        .to(new TableRefPartition(StaticValueProvider.of("MYDATA"), StaticValueProvider.of("dev"),
                StaticValueProvider.of("deadletter_bucket")))
        .withFormatFunction(new SerializableFunction<TableRow, TableRow>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public TableRow apply(TableRow row) {
                return row;
            }
        }).withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
        .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));

p.run();
```

Historically my system have two identifiers of users, new one (account_id) and old one(account_uid). Now I need to add new account_id to our event data stored in BigQuery retroactively, because old data only has old account_uid. Accounts table (which has relation between account_uid and account_id) is already converted as csv and stored in GCS.

The last func `TableRefPartition` just store data into BQ's corresponding partition depending on each event timestamp. The job is still running (2017-10-30_22_45_59-18169851018279768913) and bottleneck looks Join account_id part.
That part of throughput (xxx elements/s) goes up and down according to the graph. According to the graph, estimated size of sideInputs is 106MB.

If switching to CoGroupByKey improves performance dramatically, I will do so. I was just lazy and thought using sideInputs is easier to handle event data which doesn't have account info as well.

Comment: Please include a representative snippet of your pipeline's code, e.g. the DoFn that performs the join. We might be able to help you find a way to optimize it by other means.

Comment: Thanks @jkff , I added my code. I believe it just follows the documentation. Please indicate if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you can do to improve the performance of your code:

- Your side input is a `Map<String, TableRow>`, but you're using only a single field in the `TableRow` - `accRow.get("account_id")`. How about making it a `Map<String, String>` instead, having the value be the `account_id` itself? That'll likely be quite a bit more efficient than the bulky `TableRow` object.
- You could extract the value of the side input into a lazily initialized member variable in your `DoFn`, to avoid repeated invocations of `.sideInput()`.

That said, this performance is unexpected and we are investigating whether there's something else going on.

Comment: I also see that the job is spending *a lot* of time in GC on workers. My first suggestion will definitely help with that, but you can also try specifying a bigger instance type.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to Map<String, Integer> (account_id is actually an INTEGER) type and a new job is super fast..(2017-10-31_15_33_41-2317555316151476602).

Hmm, I learnt that TableRow is not a good choice for a convenient data structure to hold temporal data.

Do you have any idea why TableRow data is collected in the first job? I thought the same TableRow instance stays in cache on each worker until the job is done. "GC runs" means the data is destroyed and created again and again. Is it due to cache size (100Mb) limitation?

Comment: TableRow is a BigQuery-specific abstraction and is good only for two things: being read from BigQueryIO.read() and being written to BigQueryIO.writeTableRows() :) It's a good idea to use other more efficient types everywhere else in the pipeline.

Comment: I suspect that the cache here *does* hold a bunch of TableRow's, but every cache eviction and subsequent cache miss causes reloading a shard of the key/value store from GCS, and hitting disk is so expensive that your job's performance is bottlenecked by these rare (because you *almost* fit in the cache) but extremely expensive events.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I was too lazy to follow a good manner while thinking this is only one time (and supposed to be) easy migration ;-P 
Lukasz also perfectly answered my question and I was bit wondering, but I'd choose your answer as the best one because your suggestion indicated the fundamental (but difficult to notice alone) problem of my code. Again, thanks!

Comment: what do you mean extract the value of the side input into a lazily initialized member variable in your `DoFn`? I have context only in `processElement` function. can you show n example?

Answer (score 2):

Try one of:

1) setting the option using some code:

```
options.as(DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions.class).setWorkerCacheMb(500);
```

2) having your application register `DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions` with the `PipelineOptionsFactory`

3) Having your own options class extend `DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions`

Comment: Hi, the first option works perfectly :) (I think others would too) Thanks for the information!

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that the documentation on DWHO is currently somewhat misleading and should be changed to reflect that it is, in fact, safe to change this option?

Comment: How so? "These options have no effect at pipeline creation time." means that the options only apply at pipeline execution time.