# filtering Pcollections in apache beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have two Pcollections

```
P1  as Pcollection KV<String,Object>
P2 as Pcollection  KV<String,Long>
```

The Keys in both Pcollections are same, However values are different.

P1 as around 70 Million entries, P2 is subset of P1 and has 30 Million entries.

Now I need to split P1 into two collections such that P1.A will contain only the keys found in P2, while P1.B will contain keys that are not present in P2.

I dont want to use co-groupbykey or any join as it results in shuffling of data.

Can 20M entries(all strings) be used as side input probably as a HashMap  ? Is this a good approach ?

Do suggest any other optimal approaches to split P1 into two collections one which is intersection of keys in P2 while the other is minus of P2?

Answer (score 1):

Before you go for the side input based filtering, you need to consider the size of your side input view.

For instance, let us assume that your **String** keys are of **length 10**, so a rough estimate of the total size can be obtained as follows :-

```
// A sample Key of size 10, prints 20 bytes as the key size.
System.out.print("AB-2325-CD".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16BE")).length);
```

> The side input size can be calculated as  **20 * 20,000,000 = 400 MB**
>
> **Note**: This estimate does not include the storage overhead associated with a string (*and the size of your value object, provided you are passing the size input as a map*). For details on size calculation [refer](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml).

As per [View](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/View.html) class Java docs

> ... Both asMultimap() and asMap() are useful for implementing lookup based
>   "joins" with the main input, when the side input is small enough to
>   fit into memory.

The key take away here before using the *side input* is :-

- the size ratio of side input vs your main input
- Does it fit into the memory of your workers

I am not sure of the default memory available to worker but you can increase it through the [WorkerCacheMb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032203/can-i-use-setworkercachemb-in-apache-beam-2-0) property.

> Regarding your question, *Can 20M entries(all strings) be used as side
>   input probably as a HashMap ?*

The size of the side input determines the correct approach, i.e :-

> - Use View.asList, if your side input fits into [memory](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/View.html#asList--)
> - Use View.asIterator, if your side input does not fit into [memory](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/View.html#asIterable--), it will have performance penalty
> - Use View.asMap, only when you are sure that it will fit into the memory.